# The package name of your apk may not begin with any of the following values

Tags: google-play, publish

Hello everyone I have a problem.

I'm trying to upload my application in the Android Market but when I try to upload it say "The package name of your apk may not begin with any of the following values: [com.android, com.google, android, com.example]" but the package's name of my application is com.google.smile.spesaPRO. Why ?

Comment: Because the package name of your application starts with "com.google"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you observe properly, the second value in error message is 'com.google' which is same as starting of your package **com.google**.smile...  Rename your package to something else which is not listed in the message.